# 更新ボタンを押しても"selected=selected"の位置に戻らない場合の対処法

Tags: javascript, html

初歩的な質問ですが、IEでは下記のようなセレクトのボタンの表示が、
更新ボタンを押しても"selected=selected"の位置に戻りません。
javascriptで式を立てて戻るようにできるのでしたら、教えていただけ
ませんでしょうか。Chromeでは、戻ります。

```
  <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option selected=selected>d</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: 最初に開いた時には選択されているのですか？例で動くと思いますがIEのバージョンはいくつでしょうか？あと直接的には関係ないですが、`<option selected="selected">`か、`<option selected>`と書いた方が良いかとおもいます。

Comment: 開いた時には"d"が選択されています。IEのバージョンは、11です。ボタンに値を入れた場合は、それは戻るのですが、ボタンの表示が戻らないのです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ブラウザのキャッシュが効いていることが原因かと考えられます。

画面更新時にキャッシュされたhtmlファイルが使用されると、IE11の場合はフォームへの入力内容がリセットされない仕様のようです。
（キャッシュをクリアした後に更新するか、スーパーリロード(Ctrl+更新ボタン)でフォームが元に戻る事を確認できるかと思います）

ウェブサーバー側にてhttpレスポンスヘッダへ`Cache-control`等を追加し、キャッシュを無効化する対応が必要かと思います。

[参考]
キャッシュについて整理 - Qiita
https://qiita.com/anchoor/items/2dc6ab8347c940ea4648

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。原因はキャッシュが効いていることあたりかと思って検索していたのですが。仕様ですからね。